# How can I use the tkinter module to make a controller for turtle?

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I want to make a controller for the turtle module using the tkinter module.
I wrote a code myself but it didn't work. It also contains four forward, backward, left and right.

Can someone answer me and explain with a solution?

```
from tkinter import *
import turtle

def turtle():
    if Button1==1:
        turtle.forward(100)
        done()
    if Button2==1:
        turtle.backward(100)
        done()
    if button3==1:
        turtle.left(90)
        done()
    if button4==1:
        turtle.right(90)
        done()
    else:
        done()



window = TK()
window.title("turtle")
window.minsize(1000,700)


Button1(window,text="forward",command=turtle).pack()
Button2(window,text="backward",command=turtle).pack()   
Button3(window,text="left",command=turtle).pack()   
Button4(window,text="right",command=turtle).pack()
Window.mainloop()
turtle.done()
```

Comment: Your Buttons are never going to be equal to 1 (or to anything else other than themselves, actually).  There is simply no way for your `turtle()` function to tell which of the four Buttons invoked it - you need four separate functions instead.

Comment: What is `Button1` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems I see in your code include: `Button1` through `Button4` don't exist as object classes; you sometimes use `window` and sometimes use `Window`; using both `window.mainloop()` and `turtle.done()` is redundant, pick one; the `done()` function isn't defined, nor needed; you're invoking *standalone* turtle but inside a tkinter program you should use *embedded* turtle (i.e. `RawTurtle`); you misspell `Tk()` as `TK()`.

How I might go about writing the basic code:

```
from tkinter import *
from turtle import RawTurtle
from functools import partial

window = Tk()
window.title("turtle")

canvas = Canvas(window)
canvas.pack()

turtle = RawTurtle(canvas)

Button(window, text="forward", command=partial(turtle.forward, 100)).pack()
Button(window, text="backward", command=partial(turtle.backward, 100)).pack()
Button(window, text="left", command=partial(turtle.left, 90)).pack()
Button(window, text="right", command=partial(turtle.right, 90)).pack()

window.mainloop()
```